# how to consume unprocessed string?

Tags: yacc, lex

I am using Lex and Yacc to design a parser and encounter some issue about comment.

I use the following Lex rule.

```
'#'[^('\r'|'\n')]*    { /* do nothing */ }
```

It works, but at the end of execution all the comments are printed to the standard output. Is there way to clear that? Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `'`, `|`, `(`, and `)` have no special meaning in `[]`, so you're only matching (and discarding) comments that don't contain them.  In addition, in most versions of lex `'` has no special meaning at all -- only `"` can be used to quote literal strings.  What you probably want is:

```
"#"[^\r\n]*     { /* do nothing */ }
```

In addition, `#` has no special meaning either, so there's no real need to quote it.

In general, if you're using lex (or flex) as the input to a parser, you NEVER want the default echoing behavior, so its best to add a 'catch-all' rule at the very end:

```
.|\n            { fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected character '%c' in input\n", *yytext); }
```